# Функция принимающая массив из HTML тегов и проверяющая его на корректность

Tags: php

Такая задача :

Написать функцию, которая на входе принимает массив из открывающихся или закрывающихся тегов, а возвращает результат проверки корректности:  т.е. является ли принятая функцией последовательность тегов структурой корректного HTML документа.

Вот что пока имею на данный момент. Пока удалось реализовать проверку на существование тегов и на их закрытие.Буду думать как реализовать валидность корректной последовательности.

```
    function checkIfBalanced($expression)
{
    // Инициализируем стек
    $stack = [];
    // Инициализируем список открывающих элементов
    $startSymbols = ['<html>', '<head>', '<body>'];
    // Инициализируем список пар.
    $pairs = ['<html></html>', '<head></head>', '<body></body>'];

    // Проходимся по массиву, который передали в функцию
    foreach ($expression as $value){
        $curr = $value;

        if (in_array($curr, $startSymbols)) {
            array_push($stack, $curr);
        } else { // Если элемент не входит в список открывающих, значит считаем что это закрывающий символ
            $prev = array_pop($stack);
            // Составляем из этих символов пару
            $pair = "{$prev}{$curr}";
            // Проверяем, что она входит в список $pairs. Если входит, то все правильно, двигаемся дальше; если нет,
            // то это автоматически означает, что символы не сбалансированы
            if (!in_array($pair, $pairs)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    // Если стек оказался пустой после обхода строки, то значит все хорошо
    return count($stack) === 0;
}

var_dump(checkIfBalanced(['<head></head>', '<body></body>'])); // true
```

Comment: Библиотеки тут никакие не нужны. у вас на входе не документ, а массив.

вам нужен стек. идете по своему массиву тэгов, если открывающий то кидаете в стек. Если типа `img,br,hr` то игнорируете. Если закрывающий то смотрите, если на вершине стека совпадает, то убираете. Если не совпало, то структура не валидна. В конце массива, если стек остался непустой, то тоже невалидна

Comment: тут еще встает вопрос корректности дочернх элементов, что типа td не валиден без table-tr, но думаю это за рамками вашей задачи.

Comment: @teran фб игнорировал не по именам а по наличию закрывающего элемента в теге

Comment: @Ипатьев я тип элементов описал, а не метод для их фильтрации ) "типа img" то есть типа самозакрывающихся. Как он их там отсеивать будет не важно

Comment: @teran ну как бы "типа теги" это неформализуемая категория :) А как раз "как будет отсеивать" - это важно, потому что чтобы отсеять, надо сначала найти. А так это совет из серии "я не тактик, я стратег" :)

Comment: @teran Спасибо большое за наводку. Вот что пока удалось сделать. Возможно что то сделал не как вы писали, из за этого думаю как реализовать валидность последовательности тегов

Comment: @teran Понял что действительно проверять последовательность тегов возможно если изначально в массив пар ввести все возможны комбинации тегов, что естественно сумасшествие...

Comment: @Animov Привет, получилось сделать?

Comment: @IlyaDrummer Привет. Да,по крайней мере для кого это делал,устраивает.

Comment: @Animov А ты не мог бы поделится кодом который у тебя получился?

Comment: @IlyaDrummer Смотря для чего тебе нужен код